# php parsing jQuery form serialize wrong way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, xhtml

I have one problem...

These are names of some my html form elements:
    name="password"
    name="meta[naziv_firme]"

This is my jQuery

```
var data = {action: 'edit', form: $('input', 'form#edit-klijent-form').serialize()}

console.log(data);

$.get('/index.php/admin-ajax', data, 
 function(response){
  // Success
  $('div#edit-klijent-div,.tipsy').hide();
  $('div#klijent-edit-success').show();
 });
```

Console.log gives me result:

```
action  edit
form    userID=12&password=&password-match=&email=test15%5Bmeta%5Bnaziv_firme%5D=test15&meta%5Bkontakt_osoba%5D=test156&meta%5Bkontakt_telefon%5D=test157&meta%5Bkontakt_email%5D=test158
```

So everything look OK!

Now in PHP I have var_dump($_GET); and the result is:

```
string(165) "userID=12&password;=&password;-match=&email=test15&meta;[naziv_firme]=test15&meta;[kontakt_osoba]=test156&meta;[kontakt_telefon]=test157&meta;[kontakt_email]=test158"
```

Why does PHP put ; after password, in &meta;[...  ??

And ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please show us the request's query string from PHP? You can get it by doing: `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`.

Comment: action=edit&form=userID%3D12%26password%3D%26password-match%3D%26email%3Dtest15%26meta%255Bnaziv_firme%255D%3Dtest15%26meta%255Bkontakt_osoba%255D%3Dtest156%26meta%255Bkontakt_telefon%255D%3Dtest157%26meta%255Bkontakt_email%255D%3Dtest158

Comment: Could you please paste your HTML form?

Comment: `.serialize()` is intended to give you a string that defines parameters, not a string that is used **as the value of a parameter**.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML form element, add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">
```

And change this line:

```
var data = {action: 'edit', form: $('input', 'form#edit-klijent-form').serialize()}
```

Into this:

```
var data = $('input', 'form#edit-klijent-form').serialize();
```

Can't really test it since I don't have your HTML or server configuration, but I think it should work.

**Update:**

To clarify @AnthonyGrist's comment above, let's observe what serialize does:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="input1" value="foo">
  <input type="text" name="input2" value="bar">
</form>

<script>
  var data = $('form input').serialize();
  // data is now: 'input1=foo&input2=bar'
</script>
```

If you assign the value returned above to a query parameter (which PHP accesses using $_GET), you're basically telling PHP that $_GET['form'] equals the string above, which is not what you intended. PHP would not parse the contents of $_GET['form'] to give you $_GET['input1']... The value returned by serialize() should be used as the 2nd argument to $.get() directly.

Comment: Yes I know that way it works... but is that a jQuery error or ?

Comment: @user854993 The error is with the way you're attempting to use `.serialize()`. It's not supposed to be used as the value of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
var data = {action: 'edit', form: $('input', 'form#edit-klijent-form').serialize()}
```

To:

```
var data = "action=edit&" + $('input', 'form#edit-klijent-form').serialize();
```

I think it is what you're trying to achieve.